# Sentence meaning using "escorting"

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> you Back at the school, the police have started **escorting** the detained protesters to the restroom, one at a time.

Will using "escorting" sound like the police takes the protesters to the restroom to keep them there or only so that they can pee and then put them back where they were?

Comment: Common sense, rather than the grammar of the sentence, suggests that detainees are escorted to the restroom to use it, as and when they need to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**Escorting** means to take along physically. For example, He escorted me to the hotel. This can also be said as he took me to the hotel or dropped me off to the hotel. Basically to accompany a person to a place.

Definition from the Cambridge Dictionary---

> escort: to go with a person or vehicle, especially to make certain that he, she, or it leaves or arrives safely.